# Function with varying number of For loops and varying number of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing some implementation in Python 3 and I need some help. I have function, that is dependent on the dimension of matrixes. I actually have two matrixes and want to get third one in some way. For example (2-dimensional matrixes):

```py
def my_matrix_2d(mat1, mat2):
    ar = []
    for i in range(len(mat1[0])):
        ar1 = []
        for j in range(len(mat1[1])):
            try:
                ar1.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat2[i][j]])
            except IndexError:
                ar1.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], None])
        ar.append(ar1)
    return ar
```

Another example for 3-dimensional matrixes:

```py
def my_matrix_3d(mat1, mat2):
    ar = []
    for i in range(len(mat1[0])):
        ar1 = []
        for j in range(len(mat1[1])):
            ar2 = []
            for k in range(len(mat1[2])):
                try:
                    ar2.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], mat2[i][j][k]])
                except IndexError:
                    ar2.append([mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], None])
            ar1.append(ar2)
        ar.append(ar1)
    return ar
```

I need to do a general function for n-dimensional matrixes. I know it has to be something with the recursion, but I just can't figure it out. 
I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I actually didn't describe my problem very well, so I will try to give detailed description. Firstly, i will describe 2D problem. We have two matrixes, mat1 and mat2. len(mat1)=2, and let's say that len(mat1[0])=m and len(mat1[1])=n. Then, mat2 is m x n matrix, so len(mat2)=m and len(mat2[i])=n for i=0,1,...,m-1. my_matrix_2d is function, that combine this two matrixes in some way. Let's look at a concrete example: we can see mat1 as bins edges of 2D histogram and mat2 as bins heights, so mat1[0] represents bins edges in x-coordinate and mat1[1] representes bins edges in y-coordinate. mat2 represents bins heights on the intersection of x- and y-coordinate edge. So my_matrix_2d stores information about bins edges and heights of bins in 2-dimensional histogram. Its elements are vectors (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat2[i][j]), and because we need one more edge to determine the bins width, the last vectors are (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], None).

Similar in 3D example. mat1[0] (len=m) are bins edges in x-coordinate, mat1[1] (len=n) are bins edges in y-coordinate, mat1[2] (len=o) are bins edges in z-coordinate, and mat2 is mxnxo matrix that contains bins heights. The my_matrix_3d output should be matrix/array with elements (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], mat2[i][j][k]), where i=0,...,m-2, j=0,...,n-2, k=0,...,o-2, and if i=m-1 or j=n-1 or k=o-1, element in matrix should be (mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], None).

P.S. my_matrix_nd should be n-dimensional matrix, that has same shape as mat2. But elements in mat2 are floats, but elements in my_matrix_nd are len(mat1)+1 vectors.

Comment: what is the dimension of the n+1th matrix?

Comment: recursion or stack usage what imitates it. give me a minute...

Comment: Can you show a few examples of what these functions are supposed to do for n = 1, 2, 3?

Comment: btw are you sure it must be [mat1[0][i], mat1[1][j], mat1[2][k], mat2[i][j][k]]?

Comment: I edited the question and gave better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a roughly recursive implementation, with one extra parameter to specify depth of recursion (essentially, when you say it's an `n`-dimensional matrix, what is `n`?):

```
def my_matrix_nd(mat1, mat2, depth=1):
    # base case
    if depth == 0:
        return [mat2]
    # recursive case
    ar = []
    for i in range(len(mat1[0])):
        try:
            ar.append([mat1[0][i]] + my_matrix_nd(mat1[1:], mat2[i], depth-1))
        except IndexError:
            ar.append([mat1[0][i], None])
    return ar
```

It uses list slicing to cut off the first element of `mat1` for every recurrence, and isolates `mat2[i][j][k]` by passing the sublists in recursively one at a time. In the base case, it tries to just return the focal value of `mat2` (but as a single-element list, so we can prepend the other arguments onto it). And then we add successively shallower elements of `mat1` on the way back up the recursive chain.

Comment: the idea is right, but I strictly need nice matrix and can't do my job with slices...

Answer (score 0):

What about reshaping the array? do you need the n-dimensionality?

Otherwise you could transforme the two matrices in 1D arrays, build the third one
and after reshape the result

```
def operate_ndim(mat1, mat2):
    shape1 = mat1.shape
    shape2 = mat2.shape

    if shape1 != shape2: return -1 # I assume that with different shapes it breaks

    dim_1d   =  np.size(mat1)

    mat1 = mat1.reshape(dim_1d)
    mat2 = mat2.reshape(dim_1d)
    res  = np.zeros(dim_1d)

    for i in range(dim_1d):
        res[i] = mat1[0] + mat2[100] + mat2[i] - mat1[-i]   # operation rule

    res = res.reshape(shape1)
    return res
```

Comment: Actually, that is not, what I needed.  I edited my question.